# segue to specific Firebase data

Tags: ios, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableView and it has about 5 cells and each cell has a different subject. Upon clicking on the cell, I will like to segue to a view controller that is populated with Firebase data only containing posts that has the specific subject clicked.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
  FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("books").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            if let postsDictionary = snapshot .value as? [String: AnyObject] {


                self.Category = postsDictionary["Category"] as? String ?? ""


            }})
    }

 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segue" {

                let showBooks = segue.destination as! SearchTableViewController

                showBooks.categorySegue = self.Category

        }
    }
```

In my Firebase database, I have a bunch of posts made by different users and in every post, they set the category to which the post belongs to. For example, if I click on the tableView cell that has the subject: Economics, I would like to segue to a view controller that only has the Economics category.

This is how I retrieve the post attributed to certain subjects:

```
databaseRef.child("books").queryOrdered(byChild:  "category").queryEqual(toValue: categorySegue).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in



        let key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "uid")

        if(key == self.loggedUser?.uid)
        {
            print("same as logged in user")
        }
        else
        {
        self.usersArray.append(snapshot)
             self.followUsersTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:self.usersArray.count-1,section:0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }



        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the category is directly below the posts node under a uniqueID, then try this

**Example :**

```
posts
    -> post_id1
         ->category : "books"
         -> other keys

    -> post_id2
         ->category : "music"
         -> other keys
```

The query to fetch the posts by category will be like this,

```
 let strCategory = "music"
 baseRef.child("posts").queryOrdered(byChild:  "category").queryEqualToValue(strCategory).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

  print(snapshot)

})
```

---

To get the cell index on selection,

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow{
        let selectedRow = indexPath.row
        let categorySelected = Subjects[selectedRow]

    }
}
```

Comment: it's not working but I think it is from my end. This is how I populate the table view cells with the subjects `var Subjects = ["History", "Language", "Economics", "Business", "More Searches"]` when I use the code in my question to try and receive the specific subject clicked,it returns nil

Comment: how do you retrieve the category name on cell selection ?

Comment: or do you directly segue on cell section ?

Comment: I directly segue on cell selection so now I am trying to figure out how to retrieve the subject upon cell selection

Comment: thank you! ok, I am getting closer. However, when I click the cell to segue it shows nothing. Even though I know it is capturing the right information because I included a `print(snapshot)`

Comment: what happened? where are you stuck at ?

Comment: I have updated my question t include my code. When I click on the cell, it is capturing the subject's fine but in the view controller to display the post with that certain subject it displays noting